# AngularJS and web.config Redirect conflicts

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have this rule in my web.config that looks like this:

```
<rule name="netball.html" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="netball.html" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/netball" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but I have a route in angular setup like this:

```
.state('netball', {
    url: '/netball',
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/sports/netball.html',
    controller: 'SportsController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Netball'
    }
})
```

For some reason the redirect rule is messing with my route. If I remove that rule, the netball view works fine. If I add it in, doesn't work at all (shows the index page, but the ui-view is empty like it can't find the template.

Because of this, I decided to change the templateUrl to

```
templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/sports/test.html',
```

and that works. So, there is something going on with angularJS and how it displays the view. Is there anything I can do (apart from renaming all my views to something that won't get matched by a redirect rule) to stop this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense if you think about it. Your angular app is making a HTTP GET request for */assets/tpl/sports/netball.html* when it tries to load the template for the route. BUT IIS is saying "when a request with "netball.html" comes in, redirect it to "/netball".

I would suggest that you adopt a naming convention for templates, e.g. "netballTemplate.html", that way you won't get any clashes.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, if you like the answer. I need the reputation points!
Thanks!

Comment: Done, it wouldn't let me before :)